# fortify behaving strangely on adm0 SpatialPolygonsDataFrame

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I'm trying to do some plots in ggplot, which I'm much more comfortable working with than R's built in plotting function. However, with one of the file's I'm using (a SpatialPolygonsDataFrame containing a map of Kenya), when I try to call fortify on the SPDF to convert it to a data.frame, plotting the result yields odd behavior in a particularly jagged region of the border, while plot manages to work fine. Anyone have any ideas as to what's going on?

```
library(sp)
library(ggplot2)

riso <- "KEN"
query <- paste0("http://biogeo.ucdavis.edu/data/gadm2/R/", riso, "_adm0.RData")
destination <- "myfile.RData"
download.file(query, destination)
load(destination)
plot(gadm)

map <- fortify(gadm)
g <- ggplot() + geom_path(data = map, aes(x = long, y = lat))
g
```

[image: Kenya Map using plot]

[image: Kenya Map using ggplot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `group = group` to the `aes()` mappings. Wish I could explain why this works.

```
g <- ggplot() + geom_path(data = map, aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group))
g
```

Comment: Was just about to comment that I'd found this, thanks a bunch! Had to dig a bit more into what fortify was doing, basically gadm was a SpatialPolygonsDataFrame that contained one SpatialPolygons object which contained multiple Polygons objects; the group indexed the separate Polygons objects (for things like islands).