# Chloropleth map in R looks bizarre

Tags: r, ggplot2, maps

I have a data set of ~25,000 people that have complete postal codes. I'm trying to create a map of Canada at the FSA level but always seem to get bizarre results. I would appreciate if someone could point out where my mistakes are happening or what I'm missing.

```
library(rgeos)
library(maptools)
library(ggplot2)

fsas = readShapeSpatial('./Resources/FSA/gfsa000a11a_e.shp')

data = fortify(fsas, region = 'CFSAUID')
data$fsa = factor(data$id)
data$id = NULL

df$fsa = substr(df$Postal, 1, 3)

prvdr_cts = data.frame(table(df$fsa)) ; names(prvdr_cts) = c('fsa', 'ct')

plot.data = merge(data, prvdr_cts, by = 'fsa')

ggplot(plot.data, aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group, fill = ct)) +
    geom_polygon() +
    coord_equal()
```

This is my resulting plot
[image: mymap]

I got my map file from http://www12.statcan.gc.ca/census-recensement/2011/geo/bound-limit/bound-limit-2011-eng.cfm under 'Forward sortation areas'. df has two columns Person ID and FSA.

Comment: can you point to where we can find your datasets so we can reproduce your code ?

Comment: I've had maps like this in the past. I've solved it by adding group = group to aes. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26709334/fortify-behaving-strangely-on-adm0-spatialpolygonsdataframe/26711342#26711342 
You've already done this so I'm not sure why you're getting this result but I suspect something peculiar is going on here: 
`prvdr_cts = data.frame(table(df$fsa)) ; names(prvdr_cts) = c('fsa', 'ct')
plot.data = merge(data, prvdr_cts, by = 'fsa')`

Comment: Using `gfsa000a11a_e.shp` I get a rather different (and more realistic) map. See here http://imgur.com/a/KPEIH The shp file has a dimension of 86,176,488 byte. And your ?

Answer (score 0):

I've seen similar problems before when I forgot `group = group` (as @r.bot points out), but as you have that I wonder if it's because the shapefile you're using is highly detailed.

I suggest trying the `sf` package to load shapefiles which has superseded using `readShapePoly`. This has the advantages of being faster and you don't need to `fortify()`. I've also simplified the shapefile somewhat to make plotting faster. Finally, you need to development version of `ggplot2` to use the new `geom_sf()` (ATOW):

```
install.packages(c("rmapshaper", "sf", "devtools"))
devtools::install_github("tidyverse/ggplot2")    
library("ggplot2")

fsas = sf::read_sf("gfsa000a11a_e.shp")
fsas = rmapshaper::ms_simplify(fsas, keep = 0.05)

ggplot(fsas) + geom_sf()
```

[image: Final plot]

Comment: I don't understand why, but using  `gfsa000a11a_e.shp` I get a rather different (and more realistic) map. See here  https://imgur.com/a/KPEIH

Comment: @MarcoSandri That looks exactly like what I want. How were you able to do that? :O

Comment: @EmmaSmith I used "approximately" the same code of your post, but I think that the big difference is in the shp file. Initially I downloaded from the web a dataset that generates the problems described in your post. Then, I downloaded this dataset http://www.statcan.gc.ca/access_acces/alternative_alternatif.action?l=eng&dispext=zip&teng=gfsa000b11a_e.zip&k=%20%20%20%2063981&loc=http://www12.statcan.gc.ca/census-recensement/2011/geo/bound-limit/files-fichiers/gfsa000b11a_e.zip